# How do I create bounds of a 2darray tilemap in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ascii

I am creating a 2D ASCII game. Currently I have the world (leveldata) stored in a 2D array. Example:

```
"test2": [
        ["╔","═","═","═","═","═","═","═","═","═","╗","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","´","´","´"],
        ["║","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","║","´","`","`","´","`","´","´","`","´","´"],
        ["║","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","║","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","´","´","´"],
        ["║","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","▓","║","´","`","´","´","´","´","´","`","´","´"],
        ["╚","═","═","▓","▓","▓","▓","═","═","═","╝","´","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","´","´"],
        ["´","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","`","´","´","`","´","´","´","´"],
        ["´","´","`","´","´","´","´","´","´","╔","╗","´","´","´","´","´","´","´","`","´","´"],
        ["´","´","´","´","´","´","´","´","`","║","║","´","`","´","´","`","´","´","`","`","´"],
        ["´","´","´","´","´","´","´","`","´","║","║","´","´","´","´","`","´","`","`","´","´"],
        ["´","´","`","´","´","´","´","´","´","║","║","´","´","`","´","´","`","`","´","´","´"],
        ["´","´","´","´","´","´","`","´","`","║","║","`","´","´","´","´","`","´","´","`","´"]
    ]
```

I take this data, replace the tile where the player is and then paste it to the screen, like so:

[image]

I want to take this array that I paste to the screen, and crop it around the player with variable
bounds. Essentially remove any tiles that are a certain distance from a box around the player, so that the camera "follows" the player.

The problem is, tiles aren't removing the way I want them to and I am stuck on what I am supposed to do. Here is all I have so far, it takes in map data, bounds, and player position, and dumps out a custom array. I am trying just the upper bounds so far...

```
// Cropping the game screen using a camera.
function crop(width=5, height=5, x=1, y=1, map=[]) {
    let topBound = y-height;
    let bottomBound = y + height;

    let rowsRemoved = [];

    // Loop through and remove rows that are above or below the max.
    for (let row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
        if (row < topBound) {
            rowsRemoved.push(row);
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < rowsRemoved.length; i++) {
        console.log(rowsRemoved[i]);
        map.splice(rowsRemoved[i], 1);
    }

    console.log(rowsRemoved)

    // Loop through and remove columns that are above or below the max.
    // for (let row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
    //     for (let column = 0; column < map[row].length; column++) {
    //         if (column < x-width || column > x+width) {
    //             map[row].splice(map[row].indexOf(map[row][column]), 1);
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
    console.log("----")
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered, rather than constantly chopping up your arrays, just have a large fixed 2D array that never changes.  Then just change the offset (X, Y) of the top left to scroll the map.  It would be more efficient and way easier to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was to slice the array instead of splice it, and take a totally different approach.

```
// Cropping the game screen using a camera.
function crop(width=5, height=5, x=1, y=1, map=[]) {
    // Get the bounds and make sure they stay within the map's bounds.
    let topBound = y - height;
    if (topBound < 0) {
        topBound = 0;
    }
    let bottomBound = y + height + 1;
    let leftBound = x - width;
    if (leftBound < 0) {
        leftBound = 0;
    }
    let rightBound = x + width + 1;

    let rowsRemoved = [];

    // Remove rows that are above or below the max.
    map = map.slice(topBound, bottomBound);
    console.log(map)

    // Remove columns that are above or below the max.
    for (let row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
        map[row] = map[row].slice(leftBound, rightBound);
    }

    console.log("----");
    return map;
}
```